# SwiftUI Custom Picker / ComboBox

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to get a customized Picker in SwiftUI for MacOS. The best option I would like to have is a customized view which can be pressed and then shows the Picker options like a ComboBox in AppKit.

Apple achieves that in their Contact books app on Mac or the Sharing dialog of Apple is the same way.

[image]

You press the + Button and the selection comes up. Is that possible in SwiftUI?

Edit: This looks very similar like `contextMenu` in SwiftUI. But how can I set it on left click instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found `MenuButton` which does the trick for SwiftUI in MacOS.

```
MenuButton(label: Title(), content: {
    Button(action: {
        print("Clicked an item")
    }) {
        Text("Menu Item Text")
    }
})
.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
```

... with using a custom View `Title()` for my clickable button.

```
struct Title: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack
        {
            Text("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Davidev, thanks for this. Quick question: I've added other options under the `Text('Menu Item Text')` for the user to click. How can I get the user's selection in the action?

Comment: Have you found a better solution for this ?, Hard to believe there is no default combo box available in SwiftUI