# How to get a ComboBox with swiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, combobox

Is there a way to create a `NSComboBox` in SwiftUI?
When I use `Picker`, a `NSPopUpButton` is created under MacOS.

I've tried this:

```
var body: some View {
    Picker("Test:", selection: $selected) {
        ForEach(1..<10) { i in
            Text(String(i))
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

But this will get me this:

[image]

But I need a ComboBox where I can enter text as well as select from a list.

Is this even possible with SwiftUI **without** integrating an `NSComboBox` as `NSViewRepresentable`.

I've already check the following question: [SwiftUI Custom Picker / ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931746/swiftui-custom-picker-combobox)
But it's about a customised picker and not about a NSComboBox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Custom Picker / ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931746/swiftui-custom-picker-combobox)

Comment: @loremipsum: No, unfortunately not. The linked question is not about a NSComboBox.

Answer (score 7):

## VDKComboBox

Using `NSViewRepresentable` isn't as awful as I was expecting. Here's a complete implementation of an `NSComboBox` for SwiftUI:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct VDKComboBox: NSViewRepresentable
{
    // The items that will show up in the pop-up menu:
    var items: [String]
    
    // The property on our parent view that gets synced to the current stringValue of the NSComboBox, whether the user typed it in or selected it from the list:
    @Binding var text: String
    

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSComboBox
    {
        let comboBox = NSComboBox()
        comboBox.usesDataSource = false
        comboBox.completes = false
        comboBox.delegate = context.coordinator
        comboBox.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0.0, height: 10.0)            // Matches the look and feel of Big Sur onwards.
        return comboBox
    }
    

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSComboBox, context: Context)
    {
        nsView.removeAllItems()
        nsView.addItems(withObjectValues: items)
        
        // ComboBox doesn't automatically select the item matching its text; we must do that manually. But we need the delegate to ignore that selection-change or we'll get a "state modified during view update; will cause undefined behavior" warning.
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = true
        nsView.stringValue = text
        nsView.selectItem(withObjectValue: text)
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = false
    }
}



// MARK: - Coordinator


extension VDKComboBox
{
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSComboBoxDelegate
    {
        var parent: VDKComboBox
        var ignoreSelectionChanges: Bool = false
        
        init(_ parent: VDKComboBox) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        

        func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
        {
            if !ignoreSelectionChanges,
               let box: NSComboBox = notification.object as? NSComboBox,
               let newStringValue: String = box.objectValueOfSelectedItem as? String
            {
                parent.text = newStringValue
            }
        }
        
        
        func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)
        {
            if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField
            {
                parent.text = textField.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Using It:

```
struct MyView: View
{   
    @State var comboBoxText: String = ""

    var body: some View
    {
         VDKComboBox(items: ["one", "two", "three"], text: $comboBoxText)
             .padding()
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll populate your list of items dynamically; the hard-coded array of strings is just a quick example.

## Alternatives

I do realize you explicitly ruled out `NSViewRepresentable`, but I tried LOTS of other ways to imitate `NSComboBox`, including:

- A SwiftUI `Button` on top of a TextField, `.trailing` aligned
- Dynamically swapping a `TextField` and `Picker`
- A custom `Popover` linked to a `TextField`

All of that looked "foreign" in one way or another. And since `NSViewRepresentable` wasn't all that bad, that's what I settled on. It may help others in the future, so I put my implementation here even though you wanted one that didn't rely on `NSViewRepresentable`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping it would be possible without NSViewRepresentable, since the app is also supposed to run on iOS devices and I wanted to avoid all the #ifdef ;-)

Comment: Ah. NSComboBox is a Mac idiom; I don’t think there IS an official iOS version of that control. There’s a few third-party attempts, but most of those look clunky. Still, the #ifdef should be limited to the comboBox file so the pain is relatively minor. You wouldn’t need an #ifdef every time you *used* the custom comboBox.

Comment: VDKComboBox does not work correctly.  It fails to properly refresh the bindings so when using in a Master/Detail view it seems to update the property on the previously selected object.  assuming Master contains a list of objects and the detail view uses the ComboBox to bind to one of the objects properties.

Comment: @Duncan - Sounds like a problem on your end—especially if you’re binding to a property of an object in a list from MasterView. Changes to “sub-objects” like that don’t propagate as you’d expect. Your best bet is to open a new question for your exact situation; this code works great.

Comment: @Bryan I have posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213340/how-do-i-fix-the-custom-macos-combobox-binding.  If your MyView uses an ObservableObject and that gets changed the binding to the new ObservableObject seems to still reference the previous object (or the one that was used when MyView was first created.

Comment: I think the issue is that your Coordinator is not updated when the ObservableObject changes - the view is not created again, it is reused but the coordinator needs to reference the new ObservableObject, it is still referencing the original one.  Qualified with "I think" because I don't really know much about how SwiftUI works under the covers.  Suffice it to say a TextField works properly but this ComboBox does not.

Answer (score 1):

Modified VDKComboBox to pass in the binding and to update the binding when updateNSView() gets called.  This will ensure that if @ObservedObject changes the binding will be updated to reference the new @ObservedObject.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct ComboBox: NSViewRepresentable
{
    // The items that will show up in the pop-up menu:
    var items: [String]
    
    // The property on our parent view that gets synced to the current stringValue of the NSComboBox, whether the user typed it in or selected it from the list:
    @Binding var text: String
    

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self, textV: $text)
    }
    
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSComboBox
    {
        let comboBox = NSComboBox()
        comboBox.usesDataSource = false
        comboBox.completes = false
        comboBox.delegate = context.coordinator
        comboBox.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0.0, height: 10.0)            // Matches the look and feel of Big Sur onwards.
        return comboBox
    }
    

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSComboBox, context: Context)
    {
        nsView.removeAllItems()
        nsView.addItems(withObjectValues: items)
        
        // ComboBox doesn't automatically select the item matching its text; we must do that manually. But we need the delegate to ignore that selection-change or we'll get a "state modified during view update; will cause undefined behavior" warning.
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = true
        context.coordinator.textVal = $text
        nsView.stringValue = text
        nsView.selectItem(withObjectValue: text)
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = false
    }
}



// MARK: - Coordinator


extension ComboBox
{
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSComboBoxDelegate
    {
        var parent: ComboBox
        var ignoreSelectionChanges: Bool = false
        var textVal: Binding<String>
        
        init(_ parent: ComboBox, textV: Binding<String>) {
            self.parent = parent
            textVal = textV
        }
        

        func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
        {
            if !ignoreSelectionChanges,
               let box: NSComboBox = notification.object as? NSComboBox,
               let newStringValue: String = box.objectValueOfSelectedItem as? String
            {
                textVal.wrappedValue = newStringValue
            }
        }
        
        
        func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)
        {
            if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField
            {
                textVal.wrappedValue = textField.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```