# How do I fix the custom macOS ComboBox binding

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of objects and when I select one of them a detailed view displays the objects details.

This works perfectly well and the correct details are displayed in the detailed view, however when the ComboBox is used to update the field the previously selected objects properly gets updated.  Using a TextField correctly updates the currently selected objects properties.

Something is wrong with the ComboBox bindings - it seems they don't refresh and as still referencing the previously selected object.

How can I fix this ?

The list object class

```
class Station: Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject {
    static func == (lhs: Station, rhs: Station) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    @Published var id: String
    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false
    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    @Published var os: String
    @Published var installation: String
    @Published var installer: String = "" {
        didSet {
            print("\(id) didSet installer: \(installer)")
            Task {
                await controller.saveStationInstaller(station: self)
            }
        }
    }
    @Published var targetDate: String = ""
    @Published var installDate: String = ""
    @Published var notes: String = ""
    @Published var group: String = ""
    
    let controller: RolloutDBController
    
    init(id: String, lat: Double, lon: Double, os: String, installation: String, installer: String, targetDate: String, installDate: String, notes: String, group: String, controller: RolloutDBController){
        self.id = id
        self.location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: lon)
        self.os = os
        self.installation = installation
        self.installer = installer
        self.targetDate = targetDate
        self.installDate = installDate
        self.notes = notes
        self.group = group
        self.controller = controller
    }
    
}
```

The list

```
var stationList: some View {
    VStack {
        
        Text("Stations").onTapGesture {
            self.expandStations.toggle()
        }
        
        Divider()
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(dbController.stations, id: \.id){ station in
                    StationListRow(station: station, expandAll: expandStations)
                        .id(station.id)
                        .padding(3)
                        .background(station.isSelected ? Color.gray : station.color.opacity(0.25))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            dbController.selectStation(station: station)
                        }.padding(.horizontal, 3)
                        

                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 6)
                .onChange(of: dbController.selectedStation, perform: { _ in
                    if let st = dbController.selectedStation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(st.id)
                    }
                })
        }
        TextField("search", text: $dbController.searchText).onSubmit {
            Task {
                dbController.deselect()
                await dbController.getStations()
            }
        }
    }.padding(.bottom, 6)
}
```

The details view - note that "new station xxx" only appears the first time an object is selected OR is the selected object is deselected and then another object is selected.  So the view is being retained between consecutive object selections.

```
struct StationDetails: View {
    @ObservedObject var station: Station
    @ObservedObject var dbController: RolloutDBController
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
            Text(station.id).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading).onAppear {
                print("new station \(station.id)")
            }
            Text(station.installation).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Divider()
            VStack{
                TextField("os", text: $station.os).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                Divider()
                
                ComboBox(items: dbController.groups.map({$0.name}), text: $station.group)
                
                ComboBox(items: dbController.installers.map({$0.name}), text: $station.installer)

                Divider()
            }
            VStack{
                ComboBox(items: dbController.targetDates.map({$0.name}), text: $station.targetDate)
               
                ComboBox(items: dbController.installDates.map({$0.name}), text: $station.installDate)
              
                Divider()
                TextEditor(text: $station.notes).frame(minHeight: 200)
                    
            }
            Divider()
            Button("Save", action: {
                Task {
                    await dbController.save(station: station)
                }
            })
        }.padding(10)
    }
    
}
```

The ComboBox view - which I suspect is the problem - the binding is not being set correctly when a new object is selected from the list.

```
struct ComboBox: NSViewRepresentable
{
    // The items that will show up in the pop-up menu:
    var items: [String]
    
    // The property on our parent view that gets synced to the current stringValue of the NSComboBox, whether the user typed it in or selected it from the list:
    @Binding var text: String
    

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSComboBox
    {
        let comboBox = NSComboBox()
        comboBox.usesDataSource = false
        comboBox.completes = false
        comboBox.delegate = context.coordinator
        comboBox.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0.0, height: 10.0)            // Matches the look and feel of Big Sur onwards.
        return comboBox
    }
    

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSComboBox, context: Context)
    {
        nsView.removeAllItems()
        nsView.addItems(withObjectValues: items)
        
        // ComboBox doesn't automatically select the item matching its text; we must do that manually. But we need the delegate to ignore that selection-change or we'll get a "state modified during view update; will cause undefined behavior" warning.
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = true
        nsView.stringValue = text
        nsView.selectItem(withObjectValue: text)
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = false
    }
}



// MARK: - Coordinator


extension ComboBox
{
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSComboBoxDelegate
    {
        var parent: ComboBox
        var ignoreSelectionChanges: Bool = false
        
        init(_ parent: ComboBox) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        

        func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
        {
            if !ignoreSelectionChanges,
               let box: NSComboBox = notification.object as? NSComboBox,
               let newStringValue: String = box.objectValueOfSelectedItem as? String
            {
                parent.text = newStringValue
            }
        }
        
        
        func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)
        {
            if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField
            {
                parent.text = textField.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it.

Create the Binding on the Coordinator and in the updateNSView() call update the binding property on the Coordinator.  The Coordinator makes a copy of the binding (a struct?!? or some such thing)

Thanks @Asperi

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct ComboBox: NSViewRepresentable
{
    // The items that will show up in the pop-up menu:
    var items: [String]
    
    // The property on our parent view that gets synced to the current stringValue of the NSComboBox, whether the user typed it in or selected it from the list:
    @Binding var text: String
    

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self, textV: $text)
    }
    
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSComboBox
    {
        let comboBox = NSComboBox()
        comboBox.usesDataSource = false
        comboBox.completes = false
        comboBox.delegate = context.coordinator
        comboBox.intercellSpacing = NSSize(width: 0.0, height: 10.0)            // Matches the look and feel of Big Sur onwards.
        return comboBox
    }
    

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSComboBox, context: Context)
    {
        nsView.removeAllItems()
        nsView.addItems(withObjectValues: items)
        
        // ComboBox doesn't automatically select the item matching its text; we must do that manually. But we need the delegate to ignore that selection-change or we'll get a "state modified during view update; will cause undefined behavior" warning.
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = true
        context.coordinator.textVal = $text
        nsView.stringValue = text
        nsView.selectItem(withObjectValue: text)
        context.coordinator.ignoreSelectionChanges = false
    }
}



// MARK: - Coordinator


extension ComboBox
{
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSComboBoxDelegate
    {
        var parent: ComboBox
        var ignoreSelectionChanges: Bool = false
        var textVal: Binding<String>
        
        init(_ parent: ComboBox, textV: Binding<String>) {
            self.parent = parent
            textVal = textV
        }
        

        func comboBoxSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
        {
            if !ignoreSelectionChanges,
               let box: NSComboBox = notification.object as? NSComboBox,
               let newStringValue: String = box.objectValueOfSelectedItem as? String
            {
                textVal.wrappedValue = newStringValue
            }
        }
        
        
        func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)
        {
            if let textField = obj.object as? NSTextField
            {
                textVal.wrappedValue = textField.stringValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```